# (GObjectIntrospection) Segmentation fault when trying to create ibus engine using javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, gobject

GObjectIntrospection allows to use C object in any high level language. https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection

IBus is a input method framework for linux. code.google.com/p/ibus

I'm in bit of trouble using GObjectIntrospection / javascript. I tried
to create an ibus engine. same code works in vala,python. but in
javascript seg fault.
I'm using opensuse 12.1 gnome3. "ibus-devel" package provides the /usr/share/gir-1.0/IBus-1.0.gir required for GObjectIntrospection.

I'm tring to run the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs
const IBus = imports.gi.IBus;
//get the ibus bus
var bus = new IBus.Bus();
if(bus.is_connected()){
  var factory = new IBus.Factory({
  connection: bus.get_connection()
  });
   factory.add_engine({
   engine_name:"ibus-sarim",
   engine_type:typeof(this)
   });
}
```

It crashes on line 6, in "new IBus.Factory".

Terminal output,

```
(gjs:13353): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object:
assertion `object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path
(object_path)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

I can't figure out where is the problem. I tried the vala test code
provided with ibus at
https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/master/bindings/vala/test/enchant.vala
It compiles and runs fine. 
In enchant.vala line 148,

```
var factory = new Factory(bus.get_connection());
```

The code for creating Factory is same that i tried in javascript.
also in python,

```
from gi.repository import IBus
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import GObject
IBus.init()
bus = IBus.Bus()
if bus.is_connected():
    factory = IBus.Factory.new(bus.get_connection())
```

This also seems to work fine, no seg fault. But in javascript it fails everytime.
Any idea ? I'm banging on this for couple of days without any avail :(

Comment: The IBus.Factory constructor in c is at https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/master/src/ibusfactory.c line 352. there 
`IBusEngine *object = g_object_new (IBUS_TYPE_FACTORY,
                                       "object-path", IBUS_PATH_FACTORY,
                                       "connection", connection,
                                       NULL);`

and https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/master/src/ibusshare.h line 81
`#define IBUS_PATH_FACTORY       "/org/freedesktop/IBus/Factory"`

So there is no way the reporting assertion can be failed. I've no idea why its failing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IBusFactory:

```
"connection"               IBusConnection*       : Read / Write / Construct Only
```

The documentation says `"Construct Only"`. That's subject to interpretation for now, but it means to me that it is probably a private or protected class member. That said, the constructor is defined as:

```
IBusFactory *       ibus_factory_new                    (IBusConnection *connection);
```

There's that connection variable, in the constructor. Notice when you provide it exactly that way, your app works fine.

```
const IBus = imports.gi.IBus;
//get the ibus bus
var bus = new IBus.Bus();
if(bus.is_connected()){
    var factory = new IBus.Factory(bus.get_connection());
}
```

Now as for `factory.add_engine()`, the definition is here:

```
void                ibus_factory_add_engine             (IBusFactory *factory,
                                                         const gchar *engine_name,
                                                         GType engine_type);
```

That means you will have to provide the `engine_name` and `engine_type` as function parameters. This works:

```
factory.add_engine('ibus-engine-name', some-engine-type);
```

See http://ibus.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ibus/ch03.html for engine ideas. This code doesn't segfault, but it doesn't work either. It indicates the correct syntax up until `add_engine()`'s second parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs
const IBus = imports.gi.IBus;
//get the ibus bus
var bus = new IBus.Bus();
if(bus.is_connected()){
    var factory = new IBus.Factory(bus.get_connection());
    factory.add_engine("ibus-sarim", typeof(this));
}
```

Comment: the IBus*.gir is not present in ubuntu repo. You need to compile the ibus from source, the gir is generated when compiling. Or you can try to use mine from opensuse. I uploaded `/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/IBus-1.0.typelib` and `/usr/share/gir-1.0/IBus-1.0.gir` here http://www.mediafire.com/?e41bmf3owb1ud

Comment: I just figured out that the problem was in the vmware fusion. I run the code in my laptop (real opensuse) and it run fine. Firstly i was trying in my mac inside vmware(guest opensuse).
Thank you very much.